# Bundle install for activeadmin not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to run `bundle install` using this in my Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

I get :

> Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
>   Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): You need to install git to be able to
>   use gems from git repositories. For help installing git, please refer to GitHub'
>   s tutorial at https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

But I already have git installed, and also I can run git commit, git pull and others command.

I'm on windows 8, using RoR 4

Comment: 2.0.3 that's the version of gem

Comment: Nope, i have exactly the same rails version, using exactly the same gem version and everything is fine running on linux. I daresay it's a windows-specific problem.

Comment: Space on path? Probably like @ksu wrote, something related to Windows environment.

Comment: I'm using windows ( sorry for that ) xD, I have git added to my path, and in the same console I can run git commands.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to access github, over git:// and http:// you can try over http://

I have this line in my Gemfile, you can adapt it to your needs:

`gem 'activeadmin-mongoid', :git => 'https://github.com/piousbox/activeadmin-mongoid.git', :branch => 'fix_sidebar_disable'`

So for you maybe

`gem 'activeadmin', :git => 'https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'`

Also, I assume you do have git installed? Because the error says, install git ; )

`sudo apt-get install git` if you are on ubuntu, or

`brew install git` if you are on Mac OS X.

Comment: Yes I have git installed, I'm in windows 8. And yes, I have that line that you paste. Still no working :/